# Tabular format of descriptive statistics

Tags: r

I need calculate the descriptive statistic for each group separately. I have much count of groups (more than 4 000 groups).

Example of data.

```
group   price
1   100
1   200
1   300
2   400
2   500
2   600
3   700
3   800
3   900
4   1000
4   1100
4   1200
```

I need output in that table format.
How do that? Can you show me?
Thnx.

```
group   Mean    Stdev   -95%CI  +95%CI  medain  min max
1                           
2                           
3                           
4
```

Comment: just `aggregate(price ~ group, df, summary)` will do actually

Comment: thnx, i know summary function. But as you can see, it function doesn't show CI and Stdev. How display CI and Stdev)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
library(data.table)
d = data.table("group" = rep(1:4, each = 3),
               "price" = 1:12 * 100)
d[, mean := mean(price), by = "group"]
d[, sd := sd(price), by = "group"]
d[, median := median(price), by = "group"]
d[, min := min(price), by = "group"]
d[, max := max(price), by = "group"]
d[!duplicated(d[, -"price"]),]
```